# Entity Framework Code Generation not running on save

Tags: entity-framework

I have an EF5 Database First data context. At some point the designer has stopped generating the data context and entity classes when a change is made and the designer is saved.

I am using the dbcontext T4 templates and haven't changed anything else (Although I'm sure something must have been changed by accident).

Any suggestions about how I get the automatic code generation?

Comment: If your Entities are in a subfolder of your project, then this is a known issue.  Nothing you can do about it other than to move it up to the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Pawel was correct that it is a know issue, there is now a fix available in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the EF Designer shipped in VS2012 and is tracked here:
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/453